# Where are the boards for fixing the window?

Tags: firewatch

So I have to find a number of boards before I can proceed with fixing the broken window. I found one of the boards lying next to the lookout tower and a second board next to the outhouse.

However, my objective still reads "Search for more boards to repair window". I've looked all around the map and haven't found any more.

Comment: Note there's a showstopper bug whereby you can find all 5 boards, have boarded up 3 boards onto the window, and it stills asks you to board them up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 of the boards are next the lookout tower and the 3rd is next to the outhouse

Comment: There were actually 4 around the base of the lookout tower, all within about 15 feet of the bottom of the stairs.

Comment: Well, now I feel like an idiot for not looking closer. I wandered all the way down to the lake.